# Where does Xperia "backup & restore" app store the backup?

Tags: backup, sony-xperia

I use the stock Xperia "backup & restore" app to backup data like contacts, call log etc.
Then I want to backup the backup to dropbox, but I cannot find the backup anywhere on the sd card.
anyone has any idea where the backup is?

Answer (score 2):

On the Sony Xperia Z5 Compact, seems to be this file `SD-Card/Android/data/SonyBnR/Backup`

Answer (score 1):

On Sony Xperia Z1 Compact without an SD card (or when storage destination of "Internal Storage" is selected), the backups are located at `/sdcard/.semc-fullbackup` (or equivalently `/storage/sdcard0/.semc-fullbackup`, or `/storage/emulated/legacy/.semc-fullbackup`).

It seems to be exposed over MTP as `\Internal storage\storage\emulated\legacy` but gives errors when trying to copy it.
So, it needs to copied from within the phone to some other location.

Answer (score -1):

The backups are located in folder ".semc-fullbackup" on your SD card.